# Cart data is not updating using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to do a Codeigniter cart.

I got some issues in updating cart details.

**HTML/VIEW**

```
foreach ($cart as $item){ 
$output.='
      <input type="hidden" name="cart[' . $item['id'] . '][rowid]" value="'.$item['rowid'].'" >
      <input type="hidden" name="cart[' . $item['id'] . '][name]" value="'.$item['name'].'" >
      <input type="hidden" name="cart[' . $item['id'] . '][price]" value="'.$item['price'].'" >
      <input type="hidden" name="cart[' . $item['id'] . '][qty]" value="'.$item['qty'].'" >
    ';

}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Update Cart" onclick="update_cart();">
```

These hidden fields contain all the data to be updated.

**JS**

```
 function update_cart() {
    var cart = new Array();
    $('input[name^="cart"]').each(function() {
        cart.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'test/update_cart',
        data: {
            cart: cart,
            csrf_test_name: csrf_token
        },
        type: "POST",
        ,
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function update_cart() {
    $cart_info = $_POST['cart'];
    foreach($cart_info as $id => $cart) {
        $rowid = $cart['rowid'];
        $price = $cart['price'];
        $amount = $price * $cart['qty'];
        $qty = $cart['qty'];
        $data = array(
            'rowid' => $rowid,
            'price' => $price,
            'amount' => $amount,
            'qty' => $qty
        );
        $this - > cart - > update($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: The PHP construction of `$this - > cart - > update($data)` looks really awkward, and I'd be surprised if it worked. Remove the spaces within.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function update_cart(){
        var cart = new Array();
        $('input[name^="cart"]').each(function() {
          cart.push($(this).val());
    });
       $.ajax({
                url: base_url + 'restaurant/update_cart',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'cart':cart,
                    'csrf_test_name': csrf_token
                },

                success: function(data) {

                    }

        });

    }
```

change your ajax to this

Comment: not working.ig got warning Message: Illegal string offset 'rowid'

Comment: the rowid is in your controller, try to var_dump($_POST) and see what key and values it consists of

Comment: i got the value in controller like this

Comment: so you dont have any key named row_id in the array, then how can you access it,

Comment: try to check the values. the rowid and price is not getting inserted into the cart, thus val1 and all are getting inserted, check the jquery use alert to see the value that you are pushing

Comment: yeah tell me @robins

Comment: got the soln bro..:)

Comment: great bro :) happy that you did it alone :)